# Sync Keycloak user base into my back-end application

Tags: database, authentication, backend

I have the following situation:

- The application I am developing on the back-end does not have a complete authentication service, it should just use the token from another service.
- When I say that there will not be a complete authentication service, I mean that I am using an open source application for this, which is Keycloak, to delegate the authentication process to it and only check if the token that comes from the front-end is valid back- end using the public key provided by Keycloak.
- However, I would like to know how I can keep the Keycloak user base and my database synchronized, as in my back-end there are many relationships that revolve around the user.
- However, I would like to know how I can keep the Keycloak user base and my database synchronized, as in my back-end there are many relationships that revolve around the user.